# Bootstrap Modal not closing on X or Close button, but does on ESC or clicking in the overlay

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

Well, the title says it all. I have a default (copied from Bootstrap docs) modal which opens using `$('#myModal').modal();` but under no circumstances the modal closes with the dismiss X or cancel button. Console doesn't log any errors. When I press ESC or at any point in the gray transparent overlay it does get closed.

For the sake of being sure I've disabled all other javascript code in my project. I've been staring at this for an hour now. What am I missing? Have done this many times before but I'm baffled with this behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after I was sure I'd ruled any external factor out I tried using the bootstrap javascript file from BootstrapCDN.com rather than my pulled in version using composer. You know what? There was a bug in my pulled in version causing this behavior...

Answer (score 2):

I've just found that with bootstrap 4 if you create a modal with javascript and add it to the document to display it it doesn't set any listener events for the data-dismiss action, so have had to do it myself:

```
$('#modalId').on('click', 'button.close', function (eventObject) {
    $('#modalId').modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This information will be useful for some of us.
The newer version of Bootstrap, like v5, has a minor feature without which the button(Close) or (X) is not closing the Modal. You just need to add **-bs** to the **data-dismiss** attribute.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `data-dismiss` attribute as follows

In X icon

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

Close Button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```

If you have them, please copy and paste your code that might help to identify what is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Does the close button have `data-dismiss="modal"` ?

From bootstrap:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

You could try to toggle or hide manually,

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```